# How can I read a Post(by id) and their Comments who has only status > 0?

Tags: cakephp

How can I read a Post(by id) and their Comments who has only status > 0?

Here is my code:

```
$conditions= array(
    'conditions' => array('Post.id' => $id, 'Comment.status >' => '0'),
);

$post = $this->Post->find('first',$conditions);
```

And here is the error:

```
Unknown column 'Comment.status' in 'where clause'
```

My Post Model:

```
public $hasMany = array(
    'Comment' => array(
        'className' => 'Comment',
        'foreignKey' => 'post_id',
    ),
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conditions dont make much sense.
You cannot combine both in a single query right away.
The relation is 1:N.

#### If you want to find all posts to comments which are status > 0:

You need to do it the other way around.
Always query the model that has the belongsTo relations. This way it will be a single query.
If you had debugged your query you would have seen that there are many queries run - especially one for the Post and then a few extra ones for the comments.

So:

```
$this->Post->Comment->find()
```

with

```
contain => array('Post')
```

If that gives you multiple results due to multiple Comments you can use `'group'` or Distinct.

Alternatively you could make a subquery which would be a little bit slower probably.

#### If you want to find a specific post and then comments with status > 0

Use first a normal find for it without the second condition. And add contain with that condition to get all related data. Don't combine it in both, since it won't be a single query in this case anyway.

```
$options = array(
    'conditions' => array('Post.id' => $id)
    'contain' => array('Comment' => array('conditions' => array(...)))
);
 $this->Post->find('first', $options);
```

See the [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html#containing-deeper-associations).
Alternativly you can make two separate find calls (same exact result).

Comment: I just want to find an specific post and their comments. But I like to  show only comments that are active (status > 0). The CONTAIN solve my problem thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hello,

You also need to give relation to the "Comment" Model -> belongsTo "Post"

---

Thanks & Regards,
Hasmukh